# How can I use blender to feed in a series of (xyz) coordinates and output a 3D Shape?

Tags: python, 3d, blender

So as the title says I am wondering how I would go about being able to input a series of xyz coordinates and have it output a 3D shape in Blender. My current idea is to build the structure from the ground up by making a closed shape on a xy plane and then just making another closed structure on the xy plane with the z+1 and then connecting the closest points to one another.

I don't know what operations I should perform in Blender for this to work and I have little coding experience. My hope is to be able to generate a series of randomly generated 3D Shapes that I can hopefully fine-tune my algorithm to give exotic shapes rather than random ones I am getting just in python.

Comment: Hey sonicfighter! Welcome to SO. I think this question might fare better on [3D Printing Stack Exchange](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) website.

Comment: Blender has its own [SE site](http://blender.stackexchange.com) which could be more helpful than 3d printing. Look at the bmesh [sample here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html) it creates a circle, extrudes several times and then uses `bridge_loops` to join the two ends.